# Regular expressions and automata

Tags: regular-language

I'm studying Regular Expressions by reading Aho's book. I don't understand two of the statements in the book:

**Question A:**

```
1(0+1)*1 + 1 : denotes the set of all strings beginning and ending with a 1.
```

My question why is `+1` added at end of the regular expression? Shouldn't `1(0+1)*1` be sufficient?

---

I'm also having trouble with the following:

**Question B:**

> The set of strings containing only 0's and 1's that have atmost one 1  as below

```
    0*+0*10*
```

Can you explain how the solution `0*+0*10*` is arrived at, step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Question a**: `1(0+1)*1` denotes set of all strings beginning and ending with one but does not contain string `1` which has length one and starts and ends with one.

**For Question b**:
Set of strings containing atmost one `1` = `A` + `B` where
`A` is set of all strings containing zero `1`s and
`B` is the set of all strings containing exactly one `1`

So A is `0*` and B is `0*10*`
Hence we get the answer as `0* + 0*10*`

Answer (score 3):

As to question a: 1(0+1)*1 does not match the one-character string 1, which begins and ends with 1.  One needs a special case for it, which the example does.

As to question b: I cannot speak for the author.  However... Any string that contains at most one 1 is a string that either has no 1s or has exactly one 1.  Assuming that the alphabet is {0,1}, the former means any string that contains zero or more 0s, that is, 0*.  The latter, with the same assumption, means any string that contains zero or more 0s followed by one 1 followed by zero or mpre 0s, that is, 0*10*.  Combining these yields the example.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, the string that is accepted by the + 1 but not by the rest is `1`. The rest of the expressions can handle 11, but not a string where the first and last character are the same.

It's similar reasoning for the second string - 0* handles strings of all zeroes, 0*10* handles strings of 1 one.